# How to Automate a website for specific results

Tags: asp.net-mvc, selenium, testing, automation, soapui

(Scenario)- I have a ASP.NET MVC website which ask 50-100 questions, 10 questions on first page, another 10-20 on second page etc... and there is a result given on the eighth page.

To be able to test my results on my website I am currently using Selenium which has been fantastic so far, but now I am adding more questions its taking 18 hours for testing with 8 threads testing at once. The test cases are generated in excel using formulas which would generate expected results.

Currently I am using Selenium in C# to read and run through the whole journey, and compare results of expected from CSV (Excel Sheet) to the actual which is taken from 8th page of the website. But this is now taking too long since its going through the UI and since im going to have more pages it has to fill and click next on each page.

(Question) - Is there a better way than selenium to be able to test my website? , preferably a tool that would not go through UI (Is that even possible?)

I know about SOAP UI but havent used it for a normal website. I have used it before with web services and for that it was simple SOAP request which was easy.

Comment: If few pages are working fine, then others should be okay too. Why to test all the pages, you can test DB instead and that should be pretty quick. Isn't it?

Comment: @eduPeeth Many test cases still fail because of mistakes in the logic code. Testing in database could be a good idea. Thanks